# SQL Server : prevent updates to a table via user permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have never worked with users/logins in SQL Server and am having a hard time getting a grasp of it.

I am currently logging in as Administrator which sets me up as the "dbo" database user.

There is a specific table that I want to prevent UPDATES to. I tried altering permissions via

```
DENY UPDATE on SCHEMA::table TO dbo
```

but apparently you can't mess with the dbo user's permissions.

So I create a new user `myuser` and switched via `setuser myuser` but that user doesn't seem to have permissions to even select from the tables.

How should I grant "everything except update a specific table" permissions to this user?

Comment: Why were you trying to do this for `dbo`? If you are just trying to protect against accidental updates you can defined an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger that does nothing except throw an error. This is not a security measure though as anyone with appropriate permissions can disable, alter or drop the trigger.

Comment: It's not a security measure, just a precaution.  I tried `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` but it breaks my `MERGE` statements.

Comment: Ah right. Yes in that case it insists on `INSTEAD OF` triggers for the other two actions for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To  grant "everything except update a specific table" permissions you can do

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'myuser'

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'myuser'

DENY UPDATE ON dbo.YourTable TO myuser
```

[From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx)

> Members of the db_datawriter fixed database role can add, delete, or
> change data in all user tables.
>
> Members of the db_datareader fixed
> database role can read all data from all user tables.

Comment: Is there any way to switch back to user `dbo` after i've switched to `myuser`?  I tried adding `db_owner` permissions, but `setuser dbo` still fails.

Comment: Use [execute as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) instead of `setuser` and then call `revert` to switch back.